# titelsec + tcolorbox: How to put a box around the whole title line?

Tags: tcolorbox, titlesec, section-titles

I've got 2 elements in my document that I like to combine.

First a box that wraps around a whole text line:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{frameT}{enhanced, colframe=black,colback=purple!2.5, boxrule=0.2pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,frame hidden}

% in example \begin{frameT} **Text** \end{frameT}
```

And thanks to some neat packages a fancy title:

```
\usepackage[calcwidth,explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\huge\color{dblue!60}}{{{\thesection.\kern0.20em}}}{-0.15em}{\centering {\contour{npink!40}{\ul{#1}}}}

% in example \section{fancy title}
```

What's is my mind is to, well, combine those two, thus having a box wrapping around a fancy title.

I had some attempts, but none worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the tcolorbox just to the section title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\newtcbox{\frameT}{
  on line,
  enhanced,
  coltext=dblue!60,
  colframe=black,
  colback=purple,
  boxrule=0.2pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  frame hidden,
}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}

\newcommand{\frametitle}[1]{\frameT{\contour{pink!40}{#1}}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\huge\color{dblue!60}}
  {\thesection. }
  {0pt}
  {\frametitle}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `purple` without mixing just to produce an explanatory picture and removed underlining that has no real place in typography.

Personally, I'd use nothing of this kind.

---

#### Edit after comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtcolorbox{frameT}{
  enhanced,
  coltext=dblue!60,
  colframe=black,
  colback=purple,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  left skip=-1.4pt,
  right skip=-1.4pt,
}
\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}

\newcommand{\frametitle}[2]{%
  \vbox{%
    \kern-\lineskip
    \kern-0.4pt
    \hbox{\begin{frameT}\huge#1\contour{pink!40}{#2}\end{frameT}}%
  }%
}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\frametitle{\thesection.\ }}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\frametitle{}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

Filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 
filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 

\section{Test}

Filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 
filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 

\section{Test}

Filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 
filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take or leave. I don't like the code too much, but the interactions between `tcolorbox` and `titlesec` are a bit mysterious. Of course you'll remove `showframe`.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Still, is it feasible extending the color-box over the whole line? For instance ```\begin{frameT}...\end{frameT}``` will enclose the full line.

Comment: @Leon Including the section number?

Comment: Yea, and also the whole line (the empty space) Since ```\frameT``` creates a box that also encloses the empty space of the whole line.  

Would be a pleasure to get to know how to incorporate it into the title (even if it doesn't suit your taste)

Comment: @Leon Look now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!